# Swipe left is getting fired after two gestures

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.2.

I have written following jQuery mobile code to open a panel:

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {    
             $("div[data-role='page']").on("swipeleft", function(){
             openPanel();
        });

function openPanel(){
    $('#navpanel').panel("open");
}
```

However, the panel is getting opened only when I swipe left **twice**. I have written this code in index.html file in document.ready() block.

Comment: can you please also paste code for `openPanel();`

Comment: Add more context - When and where do you call it? Did you 'bind' it in wlCommonInit or elsewhere?

Comment: @Idan...I have updated the code and question. See it this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me by following the below.
That is, only 1 swipe is required to display the panel.

1. Created a new Worklight project and application with jQuery Mobile 1.4.4 (by following the wizard)
2. Changed the `BODY` in common\index.html to:

   App header
       
       
           Click to open panel, or swipe to the left...

   ```
   <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="push">
       my panel
   </div>
   ```
3. Changed common\js\main.js to:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       $("div[data-role='page']").on("swipeleft", function(){
           openPanel();
       });
   }

   function openPanel(){
       $('#mypanel').panel("open");
   }
   ```

Tested on iPhone 5s + iOS8.